# Play google drive private video in videoview android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, android-videoview, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to play google drive video using videoview of android.
I am able to play the public video of videoview using getWebContentLink as it doesn't require authentication token.
How do I stream google drive private video as I tried
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=abcxyz123&export=download?auth_token=authentication_token
But it doesn't work.
Please help.

Comment: To access a private video, I believe you need to authenticate as a user who has access to that video. You should be authenticating as someone like the owner of the video or a user who's been shared the video, otherwise you won't have the permission to access it. If it's a video hosted on Drive, you can probably use the share setting "anyone who has the url" and it should be pretty safe.

Comment: I have all the authentication, but I don't want to share the content i.e make it public, I want to keep it private and stream it.
I am able to download the content, but I am not able to directly stream the content. Is there any way to add auth token to the url and stream it directly.

Comment: How are you trying to stream it? A google drive link is accessing it through drive, not where it's hosted, so you should keep that in mind.

Comment: I am not able to find a way to get a url which can directly play a google drive private video via streaming.
Google drive app on android is able to play the video via google photos app with url of like this.
https://r2---sn-cvh7zn7d.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=c7918a69f4b75486&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=explorer&ip=223.181.51.144&ipbits=8&expire=1448290361&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=258FD95B4A6459BBA95A0727A1C443307D0DD80E.1D393C53F465017109CF8E13EE11EA9F060C87D2&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-cvh7zn7d&ms=nxu&mt=1448286656&mv=m&pl=17